# ReactDOM.findDOMNode with getAttribute("") returns null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-dom

I am defining tooltip as

```
<MACDTooltip ref="MACDTooltip" forChart={chartId} forDataSeries={dataSeriesId} key={`${chartId}-${dataSeriesId}`} calculator={macdCalculator}
                onClick={logger.bind(null, { chartId, dataSeriesId }, options)} origin={[-48, 15]}/>
```

but in `componentDidMount()` method

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.MACDTooltip).getAttribute("transform")
```

return `null`

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.MACDTooltip)
```

returns

```
 <g><g class="react-stockcharts-toottip" transform="translate(-48, 15)"...</g></g>
```

and

ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.MACDTooltip).innerHTML

return `"<g class="react-stockcharts-toottip" transform="translate(-48, 15)"></g>`

How do i use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` to get proper value

Comment: seems like you have two `<g>` tags nested, `<g><g ...></g></g>`. So the outer `<g>` tag doesn't has the transform attribute. But the inner one has.

Comment: i know, these are created by third party library so no control on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `g` tags are nested, you want to find the `childNode` of it and get the attribute from there. Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.MACDTooltip).childNodes[0].getAttribute('transform')
    );
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <MACDTooltip ref="MACDTooltip" />
    );
  }
}

// Sample MACDTooltip class for demo.
class MACDTooltip extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <g>
        <g transform="Attribute"><text>Tooltip</text></g>
      </g>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: the above code causing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ` error

Comment: What version of React are you using? And where are you calling it?

Comment: react version is 15.4.2 and i am calling it from  componentDidMount() method of the component where i am defining this tooltip

Comment: Updated my answer. Since `MACDTooltip` is a component and not a regular DOM element you'll actually have to use `findDOMNode`. Does that work?